# Filtering uneven data sets

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate, tibble

I am trying to filter out a data set into two months. I would like to filter out the `ID` and `year` that have data, and to remove the `ID` and `year` that do not have an associated pair.

For example if an `ID` and `year` has both the January and July month in the data set, I would like to include this `ID` and the `year` in my filtered data. If an `ID` has only the month of January and not July, I would like to remove this data and not include it in the filtered data set. Is there a good way to do this? Just a note that I wasn't sure how to simulate the uneven data set in the example.

After filtering for my desired output, I test by creating a list for each seasonal month where each `ID` and `year` has at least 15 rows associated with it.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)

df <- tibble(
  date = sample(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 
  1000, replace = TRUE), 
  x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
  y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
  ID = rep(1:5, 200),
  month = month(date),
  year  =year(date)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, date)

df %>%
  filter(month %in% c(1,7)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  mutate(complete = length(unique(month)) == 2) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(all(complete)) %>%
  group_by(ID, year) 

# Creates a list for each year and by ID
summer_list <- df %>% 
  filter(month %in% 7) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 15) %>% 
  group_split(year, ID)

# Renames the names in the list to AnimalID and year
names(summer_list) <- sapply(summer_list, 
                             function(x) paste(x$ID[1], 
                                               x$year[1], sep = '_'))

# Creates a list for each year and by ID
winter_list <- df1 %>% 
  filter(month %in% 1) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 15) %>% 
  group_split(year, ID)

# Renames the names in the list to ID and year
names(winter_list) <- sapply(winter_list, 
                             function(x) paste(x$ID[1], 
                                               x$year[1], sep = '_'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close. I think your filter can be simplified to the following. Just be sure to save it to `df`.

```
df <- df %>%
  filter(month %in% c(1,7)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  mutate(complete = length(unique(month)) == 2) %>%
  filter(complete)
  # could add "%>% select(-c(complete))" to get rid of complete
```

On `summer_list` and `winter_list`, add a `group_by` between the filters. With the dataset you provided, there were no groups with 15 records, but I tested that this works by bumping up the size of `df` until I got some.

```
summer_list <- df %>% 
  filter(month == 7) %>%   # used == since there's only one test value
  group_by(ID, year) %>%   # added this
  filter(n() >= 15) %>%
  group_split()
```

There's also a typo in your first use of `winter_list` -- the input data is `df1`, but I think you want `df`. Hope this works!

Here's the complete code including the larger `df`:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)

df <- tibble(
  date = sample(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 
    4000, replace = TRUE), 
  x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
  y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
  ID = rep(1:5, 800),
  month = month(date),
  year  =year(date)) %>% 
  arrange(ID, date)

df <- df %>%
  filter(month %in% c(1,7)) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  mutate(complete = length(unique(month)) == 2) %>%
  filter(complete)
  # could add "%>% select(-c(complete))" to get rid of complete

# Creates a list for each year and by ID
summer_list <- df %>% 
  filter(month == 7) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 15) %>%
  group_split()

# Renames the names in the list to AnimalID and year
names(summer_list) <- sapply(summer_list, 
  function(x) paste(x$ID[1], 
    x$year[1], sep = '_'))

# Creates a list for each year and by ID
winter_list <- df %>% 
  filter(month == 1) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 15) %>% 
  group_split()

# Renames the names in the list to ID and year
names(winter_list) <- sapply(winter_list, 
  function(x) paste(x$ID[1], 
    x$year[1], sep = '_'))
```